# Peewee python2.7 database locked error

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sqlite, peewee

I have an script that queries on a database for "blogs" and for each blog, starts a thread to query its RSS address and check for new posts and record them on the database. Initially, I was running this script with a maximum of two parallel threads (retrieving information from the rss of at least two blogs at the same time) and then, I started getting this "database locked error", now I reduced this to one, and I still get this error.

For the database connection and ORM I am using peewee 2.7.4 like this:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import SqliteExtDatabase

db = SqliteExtDatabase(APP_DIR + '/ml.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
       database = db

class Blog(BaseModel):
     (...)

class Post(BaseModel):
     (...)
```

So, starting the script it does:

```
def start():
    global ACTIVE_THREADS, MAX_THREADS
    blogs = Blog.select().where(Block.active=1)
    for blog in blogs:
        while ACTIVE_THREADS == MAX_THREADS:
            print 'Max number of threads %d reached. zzzz' % MAX_THREADS
            time.sleep(1)
        blog.processing=1
        blog.save()

        ACTIVE_THREADS += 1

        th = threading.Thread(target=process_blog, args=(blog,))
        th.daemon = True
        th.start()

def process_blog(blog):
    globals ACTIVE_THREADS
    get_new_posts_url_for_blog(blog) # here Post records are created with downloaded=0
    posts = Post.select().where(Post.downloaded = 0)
    for post in posts:
        content = get_content_for_post(post.url)
        post.content = content
        post.downloaded = 1
        post.save() #This is where the database locked error is thrown :(
     ACTIVE_THREADS -= 1
```

This is a simplified version of the script, of course, but basically that is it and at the first loop on "posts", I get the following error on the post.save():

```
File "/home/thilux/virtual_envs/ptmla/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 4573, in save
rows = self.update(**field_dict).where(self._pk_expr()).execute()
File "/home/thilux/virtual_envs/ptmla/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3013, in execute
return self.database.rows_affected(self._execute())
File "/home/thilux/virtual_envs/ptmla/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2555, in _execute
return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
File "/home/thilux/virtual_envs/ptmla/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3366, in execute_sql
self.commit()
File "/home/thilux/virtual_envs/ptmla/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3212, in __exit__
reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
File "/home/thilux/virtual_envs/ptmla/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3359, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Keep in mind that now, I am running with MAX_THREADS=1 so that there is only one blog being processed at a time. What bothers me the most is that on the first runs, I would run it with a MAX_THREADS=2 and it would go all the way through, just fine. This error just started a few days later, so I don't know if maybe on the blogs select, on the main thread, things get locked (maybe the select is attached like and I have to detach'em somehow). Could anyone please help me with this? This is really a small process and I would not like to change for another database engine, and I see performance benefits, which are also crucial, for running in at least 2 threads in parallel.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
TS

Comment: Well, in the end I decided to redesign my application to use a MySQL database after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your writes with the `atomic()` context manager.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @coleifer, but I have tried that before and yet that did not work. Now I just redesigned the whole thing and started using MySQL, much to my not wanting it that much... at least not for something so small as this...

Answer (score -2):

Don't know what peewee is and without seeing the actual SQL queries being executed, I can't say exactly what's wrong. There are two things you can do:
1. Check if there's a way to print out the actual SQL statements being executed.
2. See [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) for possible causes.